# Open word document in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have successfully done code to display pdf file in browser instead of open "Open/Save" dialog. 
Now I stuck on to display word document in browser. I want to display word document in firefox, IE7+, chrome etc.

Can any one help. I am always getting "Open/Save" dialog while displaying word doc in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't display a word document inline in the browser without writing a plugin for each browser that can understand the format and how to render it.

It is *possible* to write such a plugin for each browser, but it is a large piece of work for each browser, not to mention the actual parser and the rendering engine. This is easily a few years of work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this could help you

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2009/05/17/openxml-document-viewer-v1-released-viewing-docx-files-as-html.aspx